# Using MasterDetail Sample along with Hamburger Template in Template 10

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, template10

Has anyone used masterdetail sample of template 10?If yes **can you please explain it properly and step by step** for a novice or give the link to your code (comments included for explaination) .I have just started developing uwp apps and template 10 is good and using hamburger template  and would like a masterdetail page in that.From what i can understand that there are two implementation but how to implement that in my app i cannot understand how to do it.Is there any tutorial availabe for that?

Comment: You should definitely loook at the [MVA Template 10](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-template-10-16336?l=R3bBb1LRC_4305918554) videos.

Answer (score 0):

correct first implementation is using Visual States only

second implementation is using a control someone in the community is creating.

The switcher button shows 2 implementations..  By far the first implementation is so much easier to get started with and work other features in like using a SemanticZoom for example.

No tuts just the samples.  They are really easiest examples out there...